# Oracle: is it possible to trim a string and count the number of occurances, and insert to a new table?

Tags: oracle

My source table looks like this:

```
id|value|count
```

Value is a String of values separated by semicolons(;). For example it may look like this

```
A;B;C;D;
```

Some may not have values at a certain position, like this

```
A;;;D;
```

First, I've selectively moved records to a new table(targettable) based on positions with values using regexp. I achieved this by using `[^;]+;` for having some value between the semicolons, and `[^;]*;` for those positions I don't care about. For example, if I wanted the 1st and 4th place to have values, I could incorporate regexp with insert into like this

```
insert into
    targettable tt (id, value, count)
    SELECT some_seq.nextval,value, count
    FROM source table
    WHERE
    regexp_like(value, '^[^;]+;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]+;')
```

so now my new table has a list of records that have values at the 1st and 4th position. It may look like this

```
1|A;B;C;D;|2
2|B;;;E;|1
3|A;D;;D|3
```

Next there are 2 things I want to do. 1. get rid of values other than 1st and 4th. 2.combine identical values and add up their count. For example, record 1 and 3 are the same, so I want to trim so they become A;D;, and then add their count, so 2+3=5. Now my new table looks like this

```
1|A;D;|5
2|B;E;|1
```

As long as I can somehow get to the final table from source table, I don't care about the steps. The intermediate table is not required, but it may help me achieve the final result. I'm not sure if I can go any further with Orcale though. If not, I'll have to move and process the records with Java. Bear in mind I have millions of records, so I would consider the Oracle method if it is possible.

Comment: Should your final entry show `B;E;` rather than `A;E;`? And how do you decide which ID value to keep when you consolidate duplicates - or is that arbitrary? More sample data, including the count values and rows that will be excluded, might be useful.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes B;E; sorry my bad. I corrected it. ID is not important, it can be any generated numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to skip the intermediate table; just extract the 1st and 4th elements, using [the `regexp_substr()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html), while checking that those are not null:

```
select regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) -- first position
  || ';' || regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, null, 1) -- fourth position
  || ';' as value, -- if you want trailing semicolon
  count
from source
where regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) is not null
and regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, null, 1) is not null;

VALUE                   COUNT
------------------ ----------
A;D;                        2
B;E;                        1
A;D;                        3
```

and then aggregate those results:

```
select value, sum(count) as count
from (
  select regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) -- first position
    || ';' || regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, null, 1) -- fourth position
    || ';' as value, -- if you want trailing semicolon
    count
  from source
  where regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) is not null
  and regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, null, 1) is not null
)
group by value;

VALUE                   COUNT
------------------ ----------
A;D;                        5
B;E;                        1
```

Then for your insert you can use that query, either with an auto-increment ID (12c+), or setting an ID from a sequence via a trigger, or possibly wrapped in another level of subquery to get the value explicitly:

```
insert into target (id, value, count)
select some_seq.nextval, value, count
from (
  select value, sum(count) as count
  from (
    select regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) -- first position
      || ';' || regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, null, 1) -- fourth position
      || ';' as value, -- if you want trailing semicolon
      count
    from source
    where regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) is not null
    and regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, null, 1) is not null
  )
  group by value
);
```

If you're creating a new sequence to do that, so they start from 1, you can use `rownum` or `row_number()` instead.

---

Incidentally, using a keyword or a function name like `count` as a column name is confusing (`sum(count)` !?); those might not be your real names though.

Comment: I really like this method. Now I just need to find a way to dynamically create the sql with java, but I think I'll manage that. Also, if the source table had 5 million rows, how much time do you think the sql will take to execute? Do you think it's pretty efficient? I only have a small test database so I can't verify this atm, but I think it will still be faster than anything I write. Also, your step by step explanation is fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: I should probably rename count. You are right, it is confusing now that you mentioned it.

Comment: It won't be very efficient, but you're hampered by your data model - storing multiple values in a single column like that isn't what you're supposed to do. (You should be able to do something a bit faster with `instr`/`substr` instead as regular expressions are slower.) If this is something you'll need to do often and/or with different positions then you'd be better off redesigning your table; or if you can't, create a materialized view of the deconstructed values, or maybe add function-based indexes for each extracted element.

Comment: It's pretty much a one-time thing so as long as it doesn't take days, I'm okay with that. I'll test it out next week. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `regexp_replace` to remove the 2nd and 3rd parts of the string, combined with an aggregate query to get the total count, like :

```
SELECT
    regexp_replace(value, '^[^;]+;([^;]*;[^;]*;)[^;]+;', ''),
    SUM(count)
FROM source table
WHERE
    regexp_like(value, '^[^;]+;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]+;')
GROUP BY
    regexp_replace(value, '^[^;]+;([^;]*;[^;]*;)[^;]+;', '')
```